# Java double division positiveness

Tags: java, floating-point, integer, division, point

Why does this java code yield Positive Infinity?

```
    double d = 10.0 / -0; 

    System.out.println(d);
    if (d == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY) 
        System.out.println("Positive Infinity");
    else 
        System.out.println("Negative Infinity");
```

Comment: Because you're dividing by zero.

Comment: Negative zero? Zero can't be negative.

Comment: @David In math you are correct. In computing not necessarily. Java and many other programming languages recognize `-0.0` as a different value from `0.0`. which I admit may be confusing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While `double` distinguishes between positive and negative zero, `int` does not. So when you convert an `int` with the value 0 to a `double`, you always get “positive zero”.

`-0` is an `int`, and it has the value 0.

Divide by “negative zero” to obtain negative infinity. To do so, you need to specify the divisor as a `double` (not an `int`):

```
    double d = 10.0 / -0.0;

    System.out.println(d);
    if (d == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY) {
        System.out.println("Positive Infinity");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Different from Positive Infinity");
    }
    if (d == Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY) {
        System.out.println("Negative Infinity");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Different from Negative Infinity");
    }
```

Output:

> ```
> -Infinity
> Different from Positive Infinity
> Negative Infinity
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Negative zero is equal to zero. Therefore,

```
double d = 10.0 / -0;
```

is equivalent to

```
double d = 10.0 / 0;
```

which is positive infinity.

On the other hand, if you instead have:

```
double d = 10.0 / -0.0;
```

you will get negative infinity (since now the second value is a double, which differentiates the positive/negative zero).

Comment: Thank you! I was further confused by " double d = 10.0 / -0f;" which yields Negative Infinity. Why does the 0 as a float turn everything negative?

Comment: Yes, as @Ole V.V. pointed out, double/int does matter. I've edited my answer to answer that question better

Answer (score 0):

This one output is
`double d = 10.0 / -0;` 
===> Positive Infinity

But If you need get Negative Infinity for the output, you can change the code this one.....

`double d = 10.0 / -0.0;`

Now , you can get "Negative Infinity" for output.

Reason ---> (data types.
first you using double/int....
second option is double/double.....
)